# POST an image to the server: PNG problems

Tags: javascript, ajax, image, post

## Background

I have a function that POSTs a single image via AJAX. This function sends an image in base64 that has been submitted by the user.

```js
function loadDoc(target) {
  var file = target.files[0];
  // this just checks the format, it can be ignored
  if (validFileType(file)) {
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onloadend = function() {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open("POST", "/img_upload");
      xhr.onload = function(e) {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
          // do something with response
          console.log(xhr.responseText)
        } else {
          // do stuff with error
          console.log("Some error with the server!")
        }
      };

      xhr.send(
        // just sending file type and message to debug it on the server side
        JSON.stringify({
          file_type: file.type,
          image: fr.result.slice(fr.result.indexOf("base64") + 7, -1),
          message: "Apples"
        })
      );
    };
    fr.readAsDataURL(file);
  } else {
    console.log("Some error with file format!")
  }
}
```

## Problem

The issue here is that the server has problems decoding PNG images *sometimes* (generally but not restricted to very large images), displaying `Invalid byte` errors. I am limiting the image size on the server but it is not causing the problem and it always works with JPG images.

## Question(s)

Is this the proper way to send a *single* image to the server? Should I be using a form? In that case, what is the best way of using it without relying upon an external library? Maybe, is the error caused by the `JSON.stringify` call? Of course, it could always be an issue with the base64 decoder or the web framework I am using.

### Whole example

Check the source at https://github.com/carrascomj/dalted or the web app at https://dalted.tech.

Comment: Submitting the raw `file` directly from the user (without the `FileReader` part) allowed the back-end to obviate the base64 decoding part, and that works for all images. It is now clear that the problem was on that decoding part, but I still don't know if it is a good idea to just POST an image as raw bytes in the body.